# Calling function in initializer : Swift

Tags: swift, init

I want to call a function in initializer, but i couldn't do it

```
class someclass {

    var a : Int
    var b : Int

    init() {

        self.a = 5
        self.b = 4

        func printx () {
            println("you called the function")

        }
        printx()
    }
}

var ab = someclass()
```

Is it posible to do that something like ab.init().printx 
And
Will this printx() function execute when i initialize  with someclass()

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't do it"?  What's the error message?  (You can't access the `printx` externally, but it should execute when you create a new `someclass` object.)

Comment: I mean, when i initialized as ab = someclass()  the string " you called the function " which is supposed the printed, didn't appeared in playground.

Comment: Odd.  I put your code into a sample project, ran it, and the string printed in the debug console.

Comment: Use the REPL, not the Playground, for printouts...

Comment: @GoZoner You can see printouts in the playground.

Comment: Ah yes, if you expand the little icons.  Thanks.  Of course, my Playgrounds always crash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your questions: No - you can't reference your `printx` from outside of `init` and Yes - your `printx` will execute when `init` is called.  In Swift 1.2:

```
 20> class Bar { 
 21.     var ping : Int
 22.     init () { 
 23.         ping = 1
 24.         func bar () { println ("bar") } 
 25.         bar() 
 26.     } 
 27. } 
 28> Bar()
bar
$R4: Bar = {
  ping = 1
}
```

Defining your `printx` in `init` is perfectly viable and you should demand that it works (and it does).  Having lexically contained function definitions in Swift is critically important.  Now, if the language could allow the function name to be recursively visible...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would do something like this?

```
class someclass {

    var a : Int
    var b : Int

    func printx () {
        println("you called the function")

    }

    init() {

        self.a = 5
        self.b = 4

        printx()
    }
}

var ab = someclass()
ab.printx()
```

Consider you never call `init()` writing it but just with `someClass()`

Comment: But if you don't  complete phase 1 of initializing, you will not able to call it. Consider the situation in which init( ) apears like : prints( ) { //prints something } then self.a = 5, self.b = 4

Comment: After you set `a` and `b` phase one is complete and you can call other functions. Try it in a playground. If you call `print()` before setting `b` you will get the compiler error due to phase one not completed.

Comment: It would be very weird but you can even set `a` and `b` (phase 1 completed), call `printx()` and than change `b` ... you will print something that is already not in sync with your instance, but you can do it. You are required to just put the instance in a completely defined state before calling `print()`

Comment: Actually the problem is, this function in my implementation will change some property in the class. And some of the parameters of that function is private, which in turns function will be considered as private. But I want that function to be public. Consider some calculator app, with predefined set of operations. I want user to be able to implement and add his operations. If it is in class definition as a method, it will become private. That is why I'm trying to put it in a initializer.

Comment: Not completely clear to me your final intent. Anyway consider that it would be perfectly legal to make `printx()` a `public` function. Only `printx()` will have access to your private properties and methods. Or maybe you could consider to post another question with a more detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This question simply demonstrates a lack of understanding when it comes to scope.

The function `printx()` is not a method on the class `SomeClass`, but it a function scoped within the particular `init()` method you've defined.

As written, `printx()` will execute (and will print) when you call the `init()` method:

[image]

See the box in the right pane at the top?  That's showing us all of the console output from our playground, exactly as it would display if we ran this otherwise.

However, we cannot now call `ab.printx()` because as I stated earlier, `printx()` is not a member of the class `SomeClass`.  If we want to call `printx()` on instances of `SomeClass`, we must then define it as an instance method of the class (and if we still want to call it in `init`, we can).

Comment: I do not think i have a understanding problem in terms of scope. On the other hand; yes, i did not check the console output. I only observed the picture in the left. Thanks for pointing out.